# bluetooth PC to PC, Point To Point (P2P) connection?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, bluetooth, remote-access

***tl;dr*** I want to remotely use a different Windows PC from my desktop Windows PC over Bluetooth

I have a desktop Windows PC with a nice monitor and keyboard. I'd like to do some work on a nearby Windows PC. However, these two PCs do not share the same network. So I'd like to try connecting to the other PC over some sort of Bluetooth connection (I'd like to use Remote Desktop).

I imagine there might be some sort of "Point To Point" Bluetooth connection for this situation.  How can I run Remote Desktop over a PC-to-PC Bluetooth connection?

Comment: You need a Bluetooth PAN. 1. https://sourcedaddy.com/windows-10/creating-bluetooth-personal-area-network.html 2. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/win10-bluetooth-pan/71b0f1ed-510d-45a4-9550-4e92100e879c

Comment: Just be aware of Bluetooth limitations. It's short-range, and, I find on Windows PC's, likely to lose connection after some time.